# If statement with modulo operator

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, modulo

I tried this -

```
x=[2,3,4,7,9]
count=0
for i in x:
  if i%2:
    count=count+1
print count
```

why the count is `3` instead of `2`, as `i%2` is satusfiying only for "2 and 4"?

Comment: Open up the Python console, and do `4 % 2`, what is the result? Then do `3 % 2`, what is the result? Now which of the results would be considered "true"? The modulo operator returns the *remainder* after a division. If the division is even (like in `4 % 2`) then there is no remainder, the result is `0`.

Answer (score 4):

The modulus of 2 over 2 is *zero*:

```
>>> 2 % 2
0
```

So `2 % 2` produces `0`, which is a false value, and thus the `if` statement *doesn't* match.

On the other hand, the modulus of 3 over to is one:

```
>>> 3 % 2
1
```

`1` is a non-zero integer, so considered true.

In other words, the `if i%2:` test matches **odd** numbers, not even. There are 3 odd numbers in your list.

Remember, modulus gives you the *remainder* of a division. 2 and 4 can be cleanly divided by 2, so there is no remainder. The `if` test checks for a remainder.

Answer (score 1):

If the Boolean expression evaluates to `true`(it can be any non zero value), then the if block will be executed.

You can achieve to get all even number counts by updating code as follows :

```
x=[2,3,4,7,9]
count=0
for i in x:
  if i%2 == 0 :
    count=count+1
print count
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are having this problem is because you have signed told your code what to expect when your if statement meets a condition.
As pointed out by @Harsha, to satisfy the condition for even numbers, it should be:

```
x=[2,3,4,7,9]
count=0
for i in x:
  if i%2 = 0:
    count=count+1
print count
```

If you want to get the odd numbers:

```
x=[2,3,4,7,9]
count=0
for i in x:
  if i%2 > 0 :
    count=count+1
print count
```