# Testing the remainder from a modulo operation using conditionals

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

Takes in a number and indicates if its remainder when divided by 3 is 0, 1, or 2.

My code:

```
number = int(input("Please enter the number"))
print(number % 3)
```

How do I test the result of the modulo to determine whether the number is divisible by 3 or not?

Comment: Very nice. So what's your question?

Comment: how can I do the problem using "if" statement

Comment: Sounds to me like they want a "yes"/"no" output. If the remainder is 0, 1 or 2 output "yes", otherwise output "no".

Comment: noi don't understand

Comment: @rickdenhaan that would output "yes" for every possible input...

Comment: Oh! now I get it

Comment: wait the reminder always going to get a 0,1,2?

Comment: @wpercy yes, but that is how I interpret the question.

Comment: @WilnnyAbreu yes, the output of `x % 3` is always going to be one of 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: Would be a tad strange mathematically, to get a remainder of something divided by 3, to be, say, 100.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help.

Comment: check out this similar question [If statement with modulo operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40481623/if-statement-with-modulo-operator)

Comment: Heavily edited question to canonise and remove off topic remarks such as the needs and desires of various professors.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `if` to test the remainder from the `%` operation:

```
number = int(input("Please enter the number"))
if number % 3:   # is true if the remainder is 1 or 2
    print('Not divisible')
else:
    print('Divisible')
```